# Creation of a python dictionary using key:value pairs from d1 and value from d2

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Edited to be contain correct dummy code. -Solved by DSM-

This problem seems simple (in my head), I'm trying to find a way to "update" one dictionaries values based upon another dictionaries k,v pairs.

Dummy text:

```
>>> dict1 = {'hello':'HELLO', 'bye':'BYE', 'right':'RIGHT', 'left':'LEFT'}
>>> dict2 = {'why':['hello', 'bye'], 'direction': ['left', 'right', 'right', 'right']}
```

Result I would like: - Simply update `dict2` to contain the value of `dict1`'s key if present.

```
updated_dict = {'why':['HELLO', 'BYE'], 'direction':['LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'RIGHT', 'RIGHT']}
```

I am trying to do this:

```
updated_dict = dict()
for v in dict2.values():
    id_list = dict2[v]
    for uniq_id in id_list: 
        new_id = dict1[uniq_id]
        if updated_dict.has_key(uniq_id):
            updated_dict[v].append(uniq_id)
        else:
            updated_dict[v] = list()
            updated_dict[v].append(uniq_id)
```

This will not work due to the unhashable list. This stumps me, I can't think of a way around this problem, any ideas?

**Note** This is **not** a simple lowercase -> uppercase issue, this was simply dummy text created to capture the essence of my problem.

Comment: Are all of the different sections that would need to be substituted separated by commas?

Comment: This is more like string replacement than really about updating dict.

Comment: What happens if `dict1` contains 2 value strings that overlap eachother, like `{'string1' : 'STRING1', 'string' : 'STRING'}`?  This is really a hairy problem to try to solve unless you can restrict your data pretty severely.

Comment: @ imagine, yes I need to update the dictionary forgot the ' ' brackets around each value

Comment: and also which dict to apply? dict1 on dict2? always?

Comment: You just made the code invalid.  Do you mean to have the values of `dict1` be a `list` or `tuple`?  The current code in the question is invalid syntax.

Comment: @CppLearner Yes, you are correct this is kinda like string replacement just using dictionaries as container/ guides.  In reality dict2 is the real dataset, dict1 is a simple k,v list to translate the results in dict2 to a more human readable form.

Comment: is that just exercise or example of bad design ?

Comment: @sr2222 :( why I hate making up code. It should be a key with multiple  values (a list) behind it, these values can be duplicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wild guess: are you thinking of something like this?

```
>>> dict1 = {'hello':'HELLO', 'bye':'BYE', 'right':'RIGHT', 'left':'LEFT'}
>>> dict2 = {'why': ['hello', 'bye'], 
    'direction': ['left', 'right', 'right', 'right'],
    'example': ["don't replace me", "right"]}
>>> new_d = {k: [dict1.get(x,x) for x in v] for k,v in dict2.items()}
>>> new_d
{'direction': ['LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'RIGHT', 'RIGHT'], 
'why': ['HELLO', 'BYE'], 
'example': ["don't replace me", 'RIGHT']}
```

I've used the `get` method of dictionaries, which accepts a default value, to allow values that you don't have a replacement for to pass through unchanged.

Comment: where did you get the lists? it was just string in the original example. did u just assume he can break it into a list? i see

Comment: @CppLearner: first it was a string, then it became an invalid tuple-like example, now it's a string again even though the OP says "a key with multiple values (a list) behind it".  Your guess is as good as mine. :^)

Comment: he did say wild guess, and I actually think this will work for me. I hadn't seen the `.get`. Thanks for giving it a shot DSM

Comment: hehehe. as wild as Python :p

Comment: no no as wild as a life scientist with 100 gigs of sequence data.. i'm truly unpythonic :)

Comment: urr.. didn't see yours answer... yours is better

Comment: @segfolt oh it's okay. time to stop my chat here. :p

Comment: @DSM Your wildguess worked with a slight mod (had to account for my bad example above).  Thank you all

Comment: @DSM but you need to join the list in the final dict, right? OP wants a string as shown in example

Comment: @Kent: as I mentioned above, the example has undergone significant evolution, and the OP's example doesn't match the "key with multiple values (a list) behind it" description-- you've already explained how to do the split/join if necessary, so that's fine.

Comment: @DSM sorry, I didn't read those comments, just read your answer. ... nice answer anyway

Answer (score 3):

may not the simplest, but work for your example:

```
>>> m={ x:",".join([dict1[y] for y in dict2[x].split(", ")]) for x in dict2}
```

or

```
>>> m={ k:",".join([dict1[y] for y in v.split(", ")]) for k,v in dict2.items()}
```

result is same:

```
>>> m
>>> {'direction': 'LEFT,RIGHT,RIGHT,RIGHT', 'why': 'HELLO,BYE'}
```